# Sign of the scalar product of vectors centered at the foci in an ellipsoid

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Consider an ellipsoid for the vector $\vec{x}$ with equation

\begin{equation}
\sqrt{ \lVert\vec{x}\rVert^2+a^2}+\sqrt{\lVert\vec{x}+\vec{c}\rVert^2+a^2}=d
\end{equation}

and parameters $a$, $d$ and $\vec{c}$.

Is it true, and how would you proove, the following statement:

> The scalar product of $2\vec{x}+\vec{c}$ and $\vec{x}$ is always positive.

Specifically, $2\vec{x}+\vec{c}$ is the sum of the two vectors $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{x}+\vec{c}$ starting at the foci, ending and pointing to the point $\vec{x}$ on the ellipsoid.

Comment: Are you  sure the equation is correct?

Comment: maybe you are right, the same-major axis is not long enough. Would the veridicity of the statement change if I just chose an arbitrary major axis-length?

Comment: That scalar product is positive if the angle between vectors $\vec x$ and $\vec x+\vec c$ is always acute. But that is not the case if the ellipsoid is stretched enough.

Comment: Indeed, but I was asking between $2\vec{x}+\vec{c}$ and $\vec{x}$.

Comment: The answer to the statement is no, anyway. One can proove as an exercise of constrained optimization that if the eccentricity of the ellipse is higher than $\frac{3}{4}$ then there always is a point where $(2\vec{x}+\vec{c})\cdot\vec{x}$ is negative.